# Code for modify DB?

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

I have no idea what kind of language of programming is this, or what the method does, any help?

It could be some code for modify some DB tables?

```
ClassMethod CreateNewConfiguration(pintInsTypeConf As %Integer) As %Integer
{
    Set objRecord = ##class(Table.tInsTypeConfigurations).%OpenId(pintInsTypeConf)
    Set objNewRecord = ##class(Table.tInsTypeConfigurations).%New()

    Set objClassDef = ##class(%Dictionary.ClassDefinition).%OpenId("Table.tInsTypeConfigurations")

    Set intTotal = objClassDef.Properties.Count()
    For intCount = 1:1:intTotal
    {
        If (((objClassDef.Properties.GetAt(intCount).Relationship = 0) &&
             (objClassDef.Properties.GetAt(intCount).Calculated = 0)) ||
            ((objClassDef.Properties.GetAt(intCount).Relationship = 1) &&
             (objClassDef.Properties.GetAt(intCount).Cardinality = "one")))
        {
            Set strName = objClassDef.Properties.GetAt(intCount).Name

            Set $zobjproperty(objNewRecord,strName) = $zobjproperty(objRecord,strName)
        }
    }

    Set objNewRecord.Name = objNewRecord.rInstrumentTypes.%Id() _ "  Config B “ 
    Set intResult = objNewRecord.%Save()
    If ((intResult '= 1) || ($ZERROR '= ""))
    {
        Quit 0
    }

    Quit objNewRecord.%Id()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, @duskwuff is right, it is Caché ObjectScript code.
And in this code, just make a copy properties for some object, from class `Table.tInsTypeConfigurations` with id `pintInsTypeConf`, to new object. It is not optimized code, but anyway, it should does this task.